# Ajax навигация и подсветка кода от prismjs.com

Tags: javascript, ajax, prism

Есть сайт с **ajax** навигацией и и подсветкой кода **prismjs**, ниже 2 скриншота с загрузкой с **ajax** и без, проблема в том что при ajax не подсвечивает код.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5NjW.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF7K6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prismjs нужно вызывать тогда, когда html загружен. Если вы при ajax навигации меняете html страницы, вам нужно заново вызывать `Prism.highlightElement(node)`. Вот [тут](https://github.com/ReklatsMasters/torrent-editor/blob/master/app/components/editor/editor.jsx#L49) пример, как я использую эту библиотеку вместе с react.

Comment: Prism.highlightAll() сделал так